# Mockito + PowerMock + TestNG + Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, mockito, testng, powermock, powermockito

I'm trying add the powermock library to the working project, but I'm getting errors.

How I add it:

1) `AbsTest extends PowerMockTestCase`

2) Build.gradle dependencies

3) In some test add `@PrepareForTest({SomeClass.class})`. After this step this error occured.

In build.gradle all libraries are included.
Error occured in a place where initialize HeadlessApplication for use Gdx.* static vars.

All tests in project extend this class:

```
abstract public class AbsTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

    static {
        initGdx();
    }

    protected static void initGdx() {
        // Initialize libgdx headless for use static vars (e.g. Gdx.input.setInputProcessor)
        final HeadlessApplicationConfiguration config = new HeadlessApplicationConfiguration();
        config.renderInterval = 1f / 60; // Likely want 1f/60 for 60 fps

        new HeadlessApplication(mock(Core.class), config); <=== ERROR LINE
    }

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void initMethod() throws Exception {
        // Initialize mocks
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

Errors:

> org.testng.TestNGException:  An error occurred while instantiating
>   class ru.coolone.adventure_emulation.input.InputGroupsTest: null  at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:435)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:336)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:125)
>     at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:190)   at
>   org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:95)  at
>   org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:81)
>     at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:73)     at
>   org.testng.TestClass.(TestClass.java:38)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:389)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:167)     at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:663)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:198)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1271)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1249)    at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1107)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)    at
>   org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)     at
>   org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.testng.internal.TestClassInstanceFactory.create(TestClassInstanceFactory.java:51)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.testng.internal.PowerMockClassloaderObjectFactory.newInstance(PowerMockClassloaderObjectFactory.java:46)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory.newInstance(PowerMockObjectFactory.java:43)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:423)
>     ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not
>   initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker    at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:66)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:29)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:186)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.confirm(MockSettingsImpl.java:180)
>     at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)   at
>   org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1729)   at
>   org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1642)   at
>   ru.coolone.adventure_emulation.AbsTest.initGdx(AbsTest.java:37)   at
>   ru.coolone.adventure_emulation.AbsTest.(AbsTest.java:30)  ...
>   29 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load
>   interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in
>   sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration@7dc3712  at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadImpl(PluginLoader.java:101)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:45)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.(PluginRegistry.java:18)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.(Plugins.java:17)
>     at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.(MockUtil.java:24)    ...
>   37 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker to
>   org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker     at
>   java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)     at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadImpl(PluginLoader.java:97)
>     ... 41 more

build.gradle:

```
...
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-headless:$gdxVersion"
testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.13.1'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.3"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-testng:1.7.3"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fixed this. Im just move `initGdx();` to overloaded `beforePowerMockTestMethod()` or `beforePowerMockTestClass()` and delete mockito annotations initialization because it execute in the parent class.

fixed AbsTest class:

```
abstract public class AbsTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

    protected static void initGdx() {
        // Initialize libgdx headless for use static vars (e.g. Gdx.input.setInputProcessor)
        final HeadlessApplicationConfiguration config = new HeadlessApplicationConfiguration();
        config.renderInterval = 1f / 60; // Likely want 1f/60 for 60 fps
        new HeadlessApplication(mock(Core.class), config);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    @Override
    protected void beforePowerMockTestMethod() throws Exception {
        initGdx();
        super.beforePowerMockTestMethod();
    }
}
```

or with overload `beforePowerMockTestClass` method

```
abstract public class AbsTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

    protected static void initGdx() {
        // Initialize libgdx headless for use static vars (e.g. Gdx.input.setInputProcessor)
        final HeadlessApplicationConfiguration config = new HeadlessApplicationConfiguration();
        config.renderInterval = 1f / 60; // Likely want 1f/60 for 60 fps
        new HeadlessApplication(mock(Core.class), config);
    }

    @BeforeClass
    @Override
    protected void beforePowerMockTestClass() throws Exception {
        super.beforePowerMockTestClass();
        initGdx();
    }
}
```