# Mockito ClassCastException after using PowerMock

Tags: unit-testing, libgdx, mocking, mockito, objenesis

After [successfully integrating PowerMock into my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214653/mockito-powermock-testng-libgdx/48227469#48227469), I ran into this error: `ClassCastException occurred while creating the mockito mock`. I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008255/classcastexception-exception-when-running-robolectric-test-with-power-mock-on-mu), but it does not work. When running tests, an error occurs in the class that mocking some JRE classes. If I delete the tests in which I use verifyStatic (), then the error disappears. If I run the test with an error separately, everything works.
I tried:

1) In `Core` module, in tests folder, I add package `org.mockito.configuration` and `MockitoConfigutation`. 
If I run the debugger and set the stop point to the `enableClassCache()` method, it stops when I run the tests, which means that this class works as intended.

2) Add `@PowerMockIgnore({"*.*"})` annotation on class with error.

Example class with error:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"*.*"})
public class PersonTest extends AbsTest {
    @BeforeClass
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        mock(ArrayList.class);
    }
}
```

`build.gradle` on `Core` module:

```
...
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-headless:$gdxVersion"
testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.13.1'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.3"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-testng:1.7.3"
testCompileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18"
...
```

Error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:  ClassCastException
>   occurred while creating the mockito mock :   class to mock :
>   'com.brashmonkey.spriter.Animation', loaded by classloader :
>   'sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2'   created class :
>   'com.brashmonkey.spriter.Animation$MockitoMock$1309622717', loaded by
>   classloader :
>   'net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader@185f7840'
>   proxy instance class :
>   'com.brashmonkey.spriter.Animation$MockitoMock$1309622717', loaded by
>   classloader :
>   'net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader@185f7840'
>   instance creation by : ObjenesisInstantiator
>
> You might experience classloading issues, please ask the mockito
>   mailing-list.
>
> at
>   ru.coolone.adventure_emulation.scripts.person.PersonTest.setUpClass(PersonTest.java:160)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:451)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:163)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)    at
>   org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)     at
>   org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.brashmonkey.spriter.Animation$MockitoMock$1309622717 cannot be
>   cast to org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockAccess    at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:48)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.createMock(PowerMockMaker.java:50)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(DefaultMockCreator.java:116)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:69)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:46)
>     at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:138)
>     ... 26 more

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I had same behavior, it is the line:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"*.*"})
```

This will ignore `org.mockito.*` which causes the issue. Be more specific about what is ignored, for instance:

> @PowerMockIgnore({"org.robolectric.*", "android.*",
> "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.*"})